# PhpStorm won't recognize the methods of my object

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I am writing some Object Oriented PHP code in PhpStorm and I've run into a problem.

I see that you need to define these PHPDoc comments and I'm trying to do the same. `QuestionList` is my "active" class, the `MySQLAdapter` is my other class which handles the database and SQL queries.

I am trying to define the constructors `$sql_adapter` parameter as a `MySQLAdapter` so that when I hit <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> I can see my object's available functions but without any luck.

The first time I use my `connect()` method the IDE will autocomplete the method name, but after I initialize my `sql` field as `$sql_adapter` the IDE won't recognize my `$sql` object's methods.

What is the problem, am I not using the PHPDoc currently?

```
/**
 * @param QuestionList MySQLAdapter $sql_adapter
 */
public function __construct($sql_adapter){
    $this->questions = array();
    $this->sql = new MySQLAdapter();
    /* autocompletes this one */
    $this->sql->connect();
    $this->sql = $sql_adapter;
    /* won't autocomplete this one */
    $this->sql->connect();
}
```

Comment: Check your PHPDoc syntax for `@param` -- it is wrong

Comment: `* @param MySQLAdapter $sql_adapter` and if `$sql_adapter` must be of type `MySQLAdapter` then typehint it in the constructor definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@param QuestionList MySQLAdapter $sql_adapter` is a nonsensical typehint. It's trying to tell the IDE that `MySQLAdapter` is of type `QuestionList` with the explanation of `$sql_adapter`. That obviously makes no sense. The annotation must be:

```
@param MySQLAdapter $sql_adapter
```

Better yet, use PHP's type hinting:

```
public function __construct(MySQLAdapter $sql_adapter) ..
```

Comment: You really need both the `$param` answer and the `@var` answer both.  The `@param` will make autocomplete work for the `$sql_adapter` method-scope variable, but not for `$this->sql`.  The `@var` will make autocomplete work for `$this->sql`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use PHPDocs to have this working correctly.

For example the object member `$sql` should be declared and documented in the class:

```
<?php
class Test {

    /**
     * @var MySQLAdapater
     */
    private $sql;

    /**
     * @param MySQLAdapter $sqlAdapter [description]
     */
    public function __construct(MySQLAdapter $sqlAdapter) {
        $sqlAdapter;    // …is recognized as type MySQLAdapter through @param doc-comment
        $this->sql;     // …is recognized as type MySQLAdapter through @var doc-comment             
    }
}
```

now the IDE recognizes any uses of `$this->sql` as the type `MySQLAdapter`.

Example updated based on the comment from @ashnazg.

Comment: You really need both the `$param` answer and the `@var` answer both.  The `@param` will make autocomplete work for the `$sql_adapter` method-scope variable, but not for `$this->sql`.  The `@var` will make autocomplete work for `$this->sql`.